# Refering another xsd element in another xsd?

Tags: java, xml, web-services, xsd

I have below xsd.

### AccountDetails.xsd

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>  
 <xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://webservices.samples.blog.com" targetNamespace="http://webservices.samples.blog.com" elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified">  
      <xs:element name="Account" type="Account"/>  
      <xs:complexType name="Account">  
           <xs:sequence>  
                <xs:element name="AccountNumber" type="xs:string"/>  
                <xs:element name="AccountName" type="xs:string"/>  
                <xs:element name="AccountBalance" type="xs:double"/>  
                <xs:element name="AccountStatus" type="EnumAccountStatus"/>  
           </xs:sequence>  
      </xs:complexType>  
      <xs:simpleType name="EnumAccountStatus">  
           <xs:restriction base="xs:string">  
                <xs:enumeration value="Active"/>  
                <xs:enumeration value="Inactive"/>  
           </xs:restriction>  
      </xs:simpleType>  
 </xs:schema>
```

### Generic.xsd

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>  
 <xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://com/blog/samples/webservices/accountservice" xmlns:account="http://webservices.samples.blog.com" targetNamespace="http://com/blog/samples/webservices/accountservice" elementFormDefault="qualified">  
      <xsd:import namespace="http://webservices.samples.blog.com" schemaLocation="AccountDetails.xsd"/>  
      <xsd:element name="AccountDetailsResponse">  
           <xsd:complexType>  



              ***//TO DO : here i need to refer the element name 'Account' which is there in AccountDetails.xsd. Here i can have list of Accounts. How can i refer that?***



           </xsd:complexType>  
      </xsd:element>  
      <xsd:element name="AccountDetailsEnRequest">  
           <xsd:complexType>  
                <xsd:sequence>  
                     <xsd:element name="AccountDetailsEnum" type="account:EnumAccountStatus"/>  
                </xsd:sequence>  
           </xsd:complexType>  
      </xsd:element>  
 </xsd:schema>
```

In above Generic.xsd, in TO DO part i need to refer the element name 'Account' which is there in AccountDetails.xsd. **here i can have list of 'Account's**. How can i write that code in To DO part of Generic.xsd? Please help me too fill the TO DO part in Generic.xsd

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `type="account:Account"`. That means you'll be referencing the `Account` element in the namespace with the alias `account`. This alias has already been defined in `Generic.xsd`:

```
xmlns:account="http://webservices.samples.blog.com"
```

This alias has the right value, because the `Account` element defined in `AccountDetails.xsd` belongs precisely to that namespace

```
targetNamespace="http://webservices.samples.blog.com"
```

So you could reference the element like this:

```
<xsd:element name="AccountDetailsResponse">  
   <xsd:complexType>  
       <xs:element name="acc" type="account:Account" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
   </xsd:complexType>  
</xsd:element>
```